# what is the correct jquery selector for this

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a `div` like this:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="link1">
        <a href="#"><img src="pic1.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="link2">
        <a href="#"><img src="pic2.png"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

the a tag is hidden so i want to show it by hovering link1 or link2 I've made it this far but it's not working

```
$("#content a").hide();
$("#content div").hover(function(){
    var id = (this.id);
    $('#' + id + 'a').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector needs to have a space between the `id` and the `a` so that it's clear that you're trying to target a descendant element.

```
$("#content div").hover(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    $('#' + id + ' a').show();
});
```

That said, you already have a reference to `this`, so building the selector in a string is redundant, use `find()`:

```
$("#content div").hover(function(){
    $(this).find('a').show();
});
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update

```
 $('#' + id + 'a').show();
```

to

```
 $('#' + id + ' a').show();
```